# How to take specific data from json?

Tags: json, discord

Salute ! I am actually struggling with something I guess is json, I have this data :

```
{
'186115049171976192' => GuildMember {
  guild: [Guild],
  joinedTimestamp: 1602490080913,
  lastMessageID: null,
  lastMessageChannelID: null,
  premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
  deleted: false,
  nickname: null,
  _roles: [Array],
  user: [User]
}
```

and I want to take only '186115049171976192', the first number, but I really don't know how, thank you in advance.

Comment: `GuildMember.id`

Comment: No, it doesn't work, sorry...